# Could not able to understand Obfuscated C Code

Tags: c, obfuscation

I saw this code in http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~manuel/obfuscate/obfuscate.html (http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~manuel/obfuscate/savastio) website.But this code is very very crazy. I could not able to understand what is happening when it is happening.
Please help me. Let me know what is happening when each line is getting executed.
e.g. `printf` function is there, if we will see there is no statement called as "`Enter the number`". But still while executing it is asking "`Enter the number`". From where it is comming.
And why the code is written like this. It looks like "`n!`"(Though it means factorial).
Please help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define l11l 0xFFFF
#define ll1 for
#define ll111 if
#define l1l1 unsigned
#define l111 struct
#define lll11 short
#define ll11l long
#define ll1ll putchar
#define l1l1l(l) l=malloc(sizeof(l111 llll1));l->lll1l=1-1;l->ll1l1=1-1;
#define l1ll1 *lllll++=l1ll%10000;l1ll/=10000;
#define l1lll ll111(!l1->lll1l){l1l1l(l1->lll1l);l1->lll1l->ll1l1=l1;}\
lllll=(l1=l1->lll1l)->lll;ll=1-1;
#define llll 1000




                                                     l111 llll1 {
                                                     l111 llll1 *
      lll1l,*ll1l1        ;l1l1                      lll11 lll [
      llll];};main      (){l111 llll1                *ll11,*l1l,*
      l1, *ll1l, *    malloc ( ) ; l1l1              ll11l l1ll ;
      ll11l l11,ll  ,l;l1l1 lll11 *lll1,*            lllll; ll1(l
      =1-1 ;l< 14; ll1ll("\t\"8)>l\"9!.)>vl"         [l]^'L'),++l
      );scanf("%d",&l);l1l1l(l1l) l1l1l(ll11         ) (l1=l1l)->
      lll[l1l->lll[1-1]     =1]=l11l;ll1(l11         =1+1;l11<=l;
      ++l11){l1=ll11;         lll1 = (ll1l=(         ll11=l1l))->
      lll; lllll =(            l1l=l1)->lll;         ll=(l1ll=1-1
      );ll1(;ll1l->             lll1l||l11l!=        *lll1;){l1ll
      +=l11**lll1++             ;l1ll1 ll111         (++ll>llll){
      l1lll lll1=(              ll1l =ll1l->         lll1l)->lll;
      }}ll1(;l1ll;              ){l1ll1 ll111        (++ll>=llll)
      { l1lll} } *              lllll=l11l;}
      ll1(l=(ll=1-              1);(l<llll)&&
      (l1->lll[ l]              !=l11l);++l);        ll1 (;l1;l1=
      l1->ll1l1,l=              llll){ll1(--l        ;l>=1-1;--l,
      ++ll)printf(              (ll)?((ll%19)        ?"%04d":(ll=
      19,"\n%04d")              ):"%4d",l1->         lll[l] ) ; }
                                                     ll1ll(10); }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but saying that you don't understand obfuscated code means that the author did his / her job. You're not supposed to understand this.

Comment: Try the `gcc -E` option and see if you can.

Comment: @Chris: And??? So trying to deciper stuff is totally not worth knowing how to do? Some people do this kind of stuff for a living. Let's not close it.

Comment: I'd say the code says `n!`, non?

Comment: @Chris: I am trying to understand this. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: @KerrekSB: I know the code says n!, but how it works, I would like to know.

Comment: Like @shinkou said, run it through `gcc -E` and `indent` as a starting point. After that, try using some refactoring tool to rename all the variables and structs into something more meaningful. Then it'll at least be well-formatted slightly less obfuscated code :)

Comment: @DCoder: I don't have gcc, I use CODE::BLOCKS.

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak: Which compiler do you use with Code::Blocks?

Comment: On an unrelated note, that's some beautiful ascii art code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a start, you can get the code indented properly and remove the indirection caused by the `#define`s. The indentation can be done by [GNU `indent`](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) and `gcc -E` will do the preprocessing. Assuming the code is in `factorial.c` (this requires using the command line):

```
> gcc -E factorial.c | indent > clean_factorial.c
```

A thing to note is the preprocessing step will dump all of `stdio.h` into `clean_factorial.c`; but that is irrelevant information, so we should comment out/delete `#include<stdio.h>` before running `gcc -E`. This basically gives:

```
struct llll1
{
  struct llll1 *lll1l, *ll1l1;
  unsigned short lll[1000];
};
main ()
{
  struct llll1 *ll11, *l1l, *l1, *ll1l, *malloc ();
  unsigned long l1ll;
  long l11, ll, l;
  unsigned short *lll1, *lllll;
  for (l = 1 - 1; l < 14; putchar ("\t\"8)>l\"9!.)>vl"[l] ^ 'L'), ++l);
  scanf ("%d", &l);
  l1l = malloc (sizeof (struct llll1));
  l1l->lll1l = 1 - 1;
  l1l->ll1l1 = 1 - 1;
  ll11 = malloc (sizeof (struct llll1));
  ll11->lll1l = 1 - 1;
  ll11->ll1l1 = 1 - 1;
  (l1 = l1l)->lll[l1l->lll[1 - 1] = 1] = 0xFFFF;
  for (l11 = 1 + 1; l11 <= l; ++l11)
    {
      l1 = ll11;
      lll1 = (ll1l = (ll11 = l1l))->lll;
      lllll = (l1l = l1)->lll;
      ll = (l1ll = 1 - 1);
      for (; ll1l->lll1l || 0xFFFF != *lll1;)
        {
          l1ll += l11 ** lll1++;
          *lllll++ = l1ll % 10000;
          l1ll /= 10000;
          if (++ll > 1000)
            {
              if (!l1->lll1l)
                {
                  l1->lll1l = malloc (sizeof (struct llll1));
                  l1->lll1l->lll1l = 1 - 1;
                  l1->lll1l->ll1l1 = 1 - 1;;
                  l1->lll1l->ll1l1 = l1;
                }
              lllll = (l1 = l1->lll1l)->lll;
              ll = 1 - 1;
              lll1 = (ll1l = ll1l->lll1l)->lll;
            }
        }
      for (; l1ll;)
        {
          *lllll++ = l1ll % 10000;
          l1ll /= 10000;
          if (++ll >= 1000)
            {
              if (!l1->lll1l)
                {
                  l1->lll1l = malloc (sizeof (struct llll1));
                  l1->lll1l->lll1l = 1 - 1;
                  l1->lll1l->ll1l1 = 1 - 1;;
                  l1->lll1l->ll1l1 = l1;
                }
              lllll = (l1 = l1->lll1l)->lll;
              ll = 1 - 1;
            }
        }
      *lllll = 0xFFFF;
    }
  for (l = (ll = 1 - 1); (l < 1000) && (l1->lll[l] != 0xFFFF); ++l);
  for (; l1; l1 = l1->ll1l1, l = 1000)
    {
      for (--l; l >= 1 - 1; --l, ++ll)
        printf ((ll) ? ((ll % 19) ? "%04d" : (ll =
                                              19, "\n%04d")) : "%4d",
                l1->lll[l]);
    }
  putchar (10);
}
```

This is slightly readable, and we can do things like rename variables so that we can tell them apart easily, even if we don't know what they do yet. E.g. this will rename the struct to `structure`, and call the pointers inside it `left` and `right` (you can do this with the find-replace tool in your editor too):

```
> sed -i 's/llll1/structure/g; s/lll1l/left/g; s/ll1l1/right/g;' clean_factorial.c
```

(you have to be careful of the order, or the replacement for `lll` might conflict with `lllll`, for example).

There are some other easy things to do:

- `1 - 1` occurs a lot: replace it with `0` (and `1 + 1` too, except replace that with `2` instead of `0`).
- The line with `"\t\"8)>l\"9!.)>vl"[l] ^ 'L'` just goes along the string printing each character after xor'ing it with `'L'` (work out why! It might help to put the `putchar` in the body of the for loop, rather than in the comma-statement).
- `putchar(10)` just prints a new line.
- Know about the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

Other than that, it's just a lot of hard work. You can and should use tools like a debugger to trace the flow of execution and work out what is happening where.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt at unwrapping it, got a bit stuck on the prompt logic, so I just initialized `longC` to zero, and printed out the request for a number manually:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct StructName
{
    struct StructName *structA, *structB;

    unsigned short unsignedShortArrayA[1000];
};

main ()
{
    struct StructName *structC, *structD, *structE, *structF, *malloc();

    unsigned long unsignedLongA;

    long longA, longB, longC = 0;

    unsigned short *unsignedShortA, *unsignedShortB;

    //for(longC=0; longC< 14; putchar("\t\"8)>longC\"9!.)>vl" [longC]^'longC'),++longC )
    //;

    printf("%s", "Enter a number: " );

    scanf("%d", &longC);

    structD = malloc(sizeof(struct StructName));
    structD->structA=0;
    structD->structB=0;

    structC=malloc(sizeof(struct StructName));
    structC->structA=0;
    structC->structB=0;

    (structE=structD)->unsignedShortArrayA[structD->unsignedShortArrayA[0] =1] = 0xFFFF;

    for( longA=1+1;longA<=longC;++longA)
    {
        structE=structC;
        unsignedShortA = (structF=( structC=structD))->unsignedShortArrayA;
        unsignedShortB =( structD=structE)->unsignedShortArrayA;
        longB=(unsignedLongA=0);

        for( ; structF->structA || 0xFFFF != *unsignedShortA; )
        {
            unsignedLongA+=longA**unsignedShortA++;
            *unsignedShortB++=unsignedLongA%10000;
            unsignedLongA/=10000;

            if( ++longB>1000 )
            {
                if( !structE->structA )
                {
                    structE->structA=malloc(sizeof(struct StructName));
                    structE->structA->structA=0;
                    structE->structA->structB=0;

                    structE->structA->structB=structE;
                }

                unsignedShortB=(structE=structE->structA)->unsignedShortArrayA;
                longB=0;
                unsignedShortA=( structF =structF-> structA)->unsignedShortArrayA;
            }
        }

        for( ; unsignedLongA; )
        {
            *unsignedShortB++=unsignedLongA%10000;
            unsignedLongA/=10000;

            if( ++longB>=1000 )
            {
                if( !structE->structA )
                {
                    structE->structA=malloc(sizeof(struct StructName));
                    structE->structA->structA=0;
                    structE->structA->structB=0;

                    structE->structA->structB=structE;
                }

                unsignedShortB=(structE=structE->structA)->unsignedShortArrayA;
                longB=0;
            }
        }

        * unsignedShortB=0xFFFF;
    }

    for( longC=(longB=1- 1); (longC<1000) && (structE->unsignedShortArrayA[ longC] !=0xFFFF); ++longC )
    {
        ;
    }

    for( ; structE; structE=structE->structB, longC=1000 )
    {
        for( --longC; longC>=0; --longC, ++longB)
        {
            printf( (longB)?((longB%19) ? "%04d" : (longB=19,"\n%04d") ):"%4d",structE-> unsignedShortArrayA[longC] );
        }
    }

    putchar(10);
}
```

**EDIT:** Cleaned up a bit.